# Continuous/dashed lines in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to plot a line, that before the number *a* the line would be dashed and after the number *a* the line would be solid in matlab, for example,

```
clear all;close all;
x=0:.01:.5;
z=.51:.01:1;
f=x.^2-3*x+.5;
g=z.^2-3*z+.5;
plot(x,f,'--',z,g,'b')
```

**Is there a way to do this without spliting the interval and creating two functions?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make things a little more automated than your example like this:

```
clear all;close all;
x=0:.01:1;
f=x.^2-3*x+.5;
a = 0.5;
hold on
plot(x(x<a),f((x<a)),'--')
plot(x(x>=a),f(x>=a),'b-')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB does not have options for plotting multiple styles for the same function.
The best place to see the options is `help plot`

You can refer to the help page here.

[Plot Help page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html)